# sudo su runs without password prompt?

Tags: linux, sudo, suse

So here's the problem.  We've got the /etc/sudoers file set up so that users can run commands from /bin like "cat" or "mkdir" without entering a password.
The problem is that the "su" command is also in /bin, so if they enter "sudo su", it gives them root access without a password.
Here's the /etc/sudoers file:

```
Defaults targetpw    
%users ALL=(ALL) ALL 

root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

support ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/, /bin/, /opt/, /etc/init.d/, /elo/
support ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mysql
```

Is there a way I can deny /bin/su while still allowing the rest of the /bin commands?

Comment: ln /bin/su /dirnotinsudoers/su; rm /bin/su

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They can `mount`? Then they **have** everything to become superuser. There are some other interesting commends, too.

You *really* want to make `/etc/sudoers` a white-list, and not a black-list.

With proper file and directory access bits and user/group setings, you should not need sudo in your daily work.

Comment: Okay, so white-listing is the way to go.  Thanks!